# How to add "alt" attribute for image during upload at WP front-end?

Tags: images, uploads, front-end

At WP Front-end I create a upload form for users.

That form has three input fields (title, tags and upload).

So I want to add "**Title - Tag - file_name**" as `alt` attribute for images during the file upload.

How can I do with my code below?

```
if ($gui == 'upload') {
    if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    }
    if ($_FILES) {
       foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
           if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
              return "Upload Err: " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
           }
           $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $newPost );
       }                        
   }
   if ($attach_id > 0){
       //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
       update_post_meta($newPost,'Uploaded_Image_ID',$attach_id);
   }
}
```

Comment: First, better use `admin_url()`. Second, how exactly is the `alt`-HTML tag displayed? Does it come from caption, or something else? HInt: There's no `alt`-Tag in the meta data.

Comment: An `alt` attribute must be a meaningful, functional replacement for an image. File names are the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

The `alt` text is stored in the postmeta database table by WordPress, therefore we have to update the postmeta of the given attachment. The reference is done via the unique attachment ID, and the `meta_key` we are targeting is the `_wp_attachment_image_alt`.

So, to set the `alt` text, we can do the following:

```php
update_post_meta($attach_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', 'Your alt text');
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/